# AutoComplete with MS Access database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, autocomplete

I want to make my txtSearch textbox in Visual Studio autocomplete.
I have searched around for a long time, for some explanations and tutorials,
but the most are about SQL databases. I have a MS Access database in my application.

I want to make autocomplete suggests from my Titel colon in my database (appData/Film)

First of all, can a textbox do the job, or is a rich textbox necessary to do the job?
I don't expect code from you, but maybe an explanation or a tutorial, you know somewhere?

Thanks. And oops. Important info: My application is based on C#, and coded in Visual Studio.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well, i have set my textbox to "AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend" and "AutoCompleteSource = CustomSource".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

namespace WinAutoComplete
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection ProductList = new
        AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declare connection string
            string cnString = @"Data Source=EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=NORTHWND;" +
                    "Trusted_Connection = True";

            /*use following if you use standard security
            string cnString = @"Data Source=(local);Initial
            Catalog=northwind; Integrated Security=SSPI"; */
            //declare Connection, command and other related objects

            SqlConnection conGetData = new SqlConnection(cnString);
            SqlCommand cmdGetData = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader drGetData;

            try
            {
                //open connection
                conGetData.Open();
                //prepare connection object to get the data through
                //reader and populate into dataset
                cmdGetData.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmdGetData.Connection = conGetData;
                cmdGetData.CommandText = "Select ProductName From Products";
                //read data from command object

                drGetData = cmdGetData.ExecuteReader();
                if (drGetData.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (drGetData.Read())
                        ProductList.Add(drGetData["ProductName"].ToString());
                }
                else

                    MessageBox.Show("No data found in Products tables");

                //close reader and connection
                drGetData.Close();
                conGetData.Close();
                //set the default pattern to SuggestAppend
                //comboBoxPattern.SelectedIndex = 1;
                txtProductID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                txtProductID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txtProductID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ProductList;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                //check if connection is still open then attempt to close it
                if (conGetData.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conGetData.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBoxPattern_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //switch (comboBoxPattern.Text)
            //{
            //    case "Suggest":
            //        txtProductID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            //        break;
            //    case "Append":
            //        txtProductID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
            //        break;
            //    case "SuggestAppend":
            //        txtProductID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            //        break;
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

This  definitely works, as you can see in the screen shot below.

[image]

Also, check this out when you have a chance.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Sorry, i just saw your message now. I will take a look on it!, and respond! Thanks! :)

Comment: Hello again, now i have just tried to get it work for many hours, and can't get it work :(

Comment: Ok, I just updated my post.  Copy/paste the code and make the necessary changes (server name, table name, field name, etc.).  This will definitely work.

Comment: Yay, it works now! Thanks alot! But there is a little problem, when i press enter, to finish the search, and to get the DataGridView find the movie, nothing happens anymore. Before i insert this, my search show up in my DataGridView. So im almost done, but this little thing, can you tell how to fix that too?

Comment: I fixed the last issue my self! THANKS for your help!